# How to get Coco Lopez in Serbia?

Tags: cream, coconut, cocktails

How can I get Coco Lopez cream of coconut in Serbia? I've looked everywhere on the internet, and it is always around $90 shipping or so. I bought it in Italy before and it wasn’t that expensive.

I need it to make Piña Coladas. I know the drink can be made from similar things, but I am only interested in this here.

Comment: There's a "Thai People in Serbia" facebook group !! (yeah really), you could ask them.

Comment: Or you could ask your local grocer if they will stock it for you.

Comment: Please note that shopping advice of the “which shop sells X” kind is not a good fit. Questions about how to find X in a more abstract sense or even better, how to make something are ok. As the answer focuses on said alternative, we can keep the question for now.

Answer (score 2):

this looks like a question about logistics and I really don't know about shipping things to Serbia, but since you mention you only need it for Piña Colada, I have good news: you can make your own cream of coconut!

Find a can of full fat coconut milk (this should be way easier to source than Coco Lopez), ideally not under 10% fat content. Add sugar (Darcy O'Neil, who [popularised this recipe](https://www.artofdrink.com/ingredient/cream-of-coconut-recipe), says 375 grams) and a pinch of salt, heat to dissolve, and you're done.

Homemade cream of coconut will not last as long as Coco Lopez and needs to be refrigerated, but it's as good (or better), cheaper, and easier to come by

Comment: She says, on 400ml of coconut cream, goes 375 grams (1¼ cups) sugar. How is 1 cup of sugar almost half of kilo?

Comment: 1 cup sugar is 200 g, so 1 cup plus ¾ (not ¼!) adds up to 350 g

Comment: ok, that makes sense. In the recipe you gave the link it says 1 and 1/4 cup....i made the thing, now let's see. I have to wait for it to congeal a little bit.